# Varying the Size of a Structure?

Tags: c, structure, flexible-array-member

I have created a structure called Register, with around 8 fields within it. I now want to create a structure called Instrument, which should have a variable amount of of fields, 6 which are the same for every instrument, plus a certain amount of fields depending on how many registers are attributed to it. How can I create this?

For clarity here is what I would like to create (although may not be accurate).

```
    typedef struct {
   int    x;
   int    y;
   int    z;
} Register;

 typedef struct {
       int    x;
       int    y;
       int    z;
       Register Reg1;
       Register Reg2;
       ...
    } Instrument;
```

Comment: @iwin did you mean flexible array member?

Comment: Another possible solution is a union of the different register possibilities.

Comment: @ikegami unions can be used instruments with less regs waste a lot of memory.

Comment: That is the potential downside, yes. The advantage over pointers are simplicity and reduced overhead. The advantage over flexible array members is that it doesn't require all the registers of an instrument to be of the same type, it doesn't require the registers of every instrument to be the same type, it allows the registers to be named instead of simply indexed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) to achieve the same.

Something like

```
typedef struct {
       int    x;
       int    y;
       int    z;
       Register Reg1;
       Register Reg2;  //upto this is fixed....
       Register Reg[];
       } Instrument;
```

and then, you can allocate memory as needed to `someVar.Reg` later.

For an example, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.2.1/20

> *EXAMPLE 2* After the declaration:
>
> ```
>    struct s { int n; double d[]; };
> ```
>
> the structure `struct s` has a flexible array member `d`. A typical way to use this is:
>
> ```
> int m = /* some value */;
> struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));
> ```
>
> and assuming that the call to `malloc` succeeds, the object pointed to by `p` behaves, for most purposes, as if
>   `p` had been declared as:
>
> ```
> struct { int n; double d[m]; } *p;
> ```

Comment: Thanks, would that be using malloc()? If so, how and where would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Mst137 I did not get what you want to know exactly.... are you talking about the above example?

Comment: Sorry I didnt see the example at the time, thats great. Thank you!

Comment: @Mst137 Welcome. :)

Comment: Tip: `Register regs[];` probably makes more sense than `Register Reg1; Register Reg2; Register Reg[];`

Comment: @ikegami I did that initially, but just to keep parity with the requirement given in the question, I updated my snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pointers

```
typedef struct 
{
   int    x;
   int    y;
   int    z;
   Register *reg;
} Instrument;
```

use it into code

```
Instrument a.reg = malloc(sizeof(Register)*NUM_OF_REGISTERS);
if (a.reg != NULL)
{
   // your STUFF
   free(a.Reg);
}
```